# Weird spam message overlay appears on my iPhone's screen (FLASH SMS)

Tags: ios, messages, services, iphone

This weird message keeps appearing every few days and it's very irritating. It always contains spam messages that asks me to accept or cancel invitations to random services (weekly jokes, pics etc). From googling, I believe this is some sort of Flash SMS:

[image]

Can someone explain if this is caused by an app or forced through the service provider as I would like to know how to disable these permanently.

Comment: I've never had the misfortune of receiving these, but if no one has a quick fix, you could disable SMS entirely and / or contact your carrier about getting detailed SMS reporting for a time frame while you debug this. I don't think iOS has a log file or setting that lets you capture SMS before it's been accepted.

Comment: Like @bmike, I also have never seen these, but have heard of them.  I am not sure if disabling SMS actually blocks these.  I think talking to your carrier is the first thing you should do.

Comment: @bmike Can these be caused by an application that I downloaded ? Or are these always related to the network operator ?

Comment: @zigg please check msgs above

Comment: I believe they can only come via your carrier, though they are likely to originate elsewhere.  Have you talked to your carrier yet?

Comment: @zigg yeah, they say that they do not send Flash SMS ... and asked me to make sure I don't have any suspicious apps that can allow such ads to appear.

Comment: That happens to me too, after digging deep, it turned out to be promotional messages from the carrier, supported by law! Of course it is annoying, I am still waiting for this tough cookie who will create an App that scans the content of these messages and decide to automatically click "Cancel" besides that, there is no real solution

Answer (score 1):

Chances are your phone number was used by someone (else, or had belonged to someone before it got cycled to you) and they had subscribed to those services. If your phone bill is clean meaning there are no odd fees showing up out of the blue then I doubt it is an app.

My personal experience. I once installed an App on my iPhone and like a dumb idiot in a rush to get to work I loaded and accepted the usage terms (why would I read 45 pages).... well shortly there after I was getting billed an extra 20 Euros a month. Had to change my contract with my provider.

Another story, I was recently overseas and needed a prepaid SIM for my phone. I put it in and everything seemed fine until I was getting random SMS with jokes, weather, and sports that I didn't need nor had personally subscribed too. But the person who had my phone number before me had subscribed.

Best thing to do is contact your provider in any case and see if they can block the attempts on their side so that you don't get harassed anymore. Sorry to hear of your woes.

Comment: Can they be blocked in any way ?

Comment: Blocked in? I don't quite get your meaning

Comment: Can the Flash SMSs be blocked in any way ?

Comment: If there is any hint/sign of the company sending the messages then I would check their website or google the company name +sms unsubscribe. That is all the tricks I know