# Is this iPhone alert Trojan/Malware?

Tags: iphone, sms, cellular-carriers, malware

Once in a while I get this bizarre behavior on my iPhone 5's screen with iOS 8.3.1. (The button says 'Approve' - in Hebrew).

I can't say if its SMS/MMS or something else. But it feels like Malware.

1. Anyone familiar with this behavior or something similar?
2. What should I do next?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to call someone who was unavailable lately? I get similar notifications when the number I have called becomes available (but in my case I can see the number).

Comment: Due to iOS' security model, installation of malware is next to, if not completely, impossible.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a "Flash SMS" or "class 0 message", supposedly only available to be sent by your carrier, but available to others via Apps ([Apple App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/flash-sms-class-0/id723491224?mt=8), [Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jomegasoft.flashsmsnoad2&hl=en)) and in some carriers, by prefixing your message with `*go`.

There are more technical details on [this answer at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24136289/2062591), specially in this [linked article](http://blog.richpollock.com/2014/06/class-0-sms-messages/):

> As per the [SMS specification](http://www.3gpp.org/DynaReport/23040.htm), after pressing “Dismiss”, the overlay and message disappear and the message is immediately discarded, leaving no trace of its delivery on the phone

I wouldn't worry much, but be sure to check your bills as it may be a sneaky way to forcing you into those pesky SMS subscription schemes, as referenced by [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/113698/38539) here on Ask Different.